# getting error: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

i keep getting error said:  Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

i try to change innerHTML ->innerText. still not working.

what am i missing here???

```
  function countdown(minutes) {
          var seconds = 60;
          var mins = minutes
          function tick() {
              var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
              var current_minutes = mins-1;
              seconds--;
              counter.innerHTML = 
    current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
              if( seconds > 0 ) {
                setTimeout(tick, 1000);
              } else {
                if(mins > 1){
                  // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by      
 Victor Streithorst    
                  setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);
              }
            }
        }
        tick();
    }        
    countdown(3);
```

html

```
   <div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: your <div> isn´t rendered when your code is executed, you need to execute your code after pageload

Comment: Call the countdown function after the <div id="timer"></div>. Also you can use jQuery document ready if you wish to use jQuery.

Comment: You have some typos, fix them (missing ; and ,)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/fijikewotuwu/1/edit its working :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `countdown()`, which calls `tick()`, which calls `document.getElementById("timer")`, *before that element has even been parsed*.

Try doing it like this:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
        var current_minutes = mins-1
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {

            if(mins > 1) {
                // countdown(mins-1);
                setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
    tick();
}

countdown(3);
</script>
```

In this case, order matters. You want to make sure the document has encountered that element before accessing it via the DOM.